# Check text field empty please help me

Tags: python, kivy, kivymd

````
class ReviewinApp(MDApp):
    def build(self):
        dialog = None
        self.title = "ReviewinApp"
        global sm 
        sm = ScreenManager()
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("splash.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("accueil.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file('conditions.kv'))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("register.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("faq.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("login.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("User2.kv"))
        sm.add_widget(Builder.load_file("rules.kv"))
        return sm
    def check_register(self, text):
        user = self.ids.user_app.text 
        if user == "":
            toast("pls")
        else:
            toast("okay")
    ```
            MDFillRoundFlatButton:
            text: "Finish !"
            font_size: "20sp"
            font_name: "OpenSans"
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.07}
            halign: 'center'
            theme_text_color:'Custom'
            text_color: 255/255, 255/255, 255/255, 1
            size_hint: (0.58, 0.06)
            md_bg_color: 62/255, 216/255, 133/255, 1
            background_normal:''
            on_press: app.check_register(self.text) 
    ```
   
    ```
            MDTextFieldRound:
            id:user_app
            text: ""
            hint_text: "Full Name"
            size_hint_x:  None
            size_hint_y: 0.08
            width: 247
            font_size: 18
            pos_hint: {'center_x':0.5, 'center_y':0.62}
````

I really do not understand...I really do not understand, it's been for 2 weeks I'am trying... Please help me. I tried to do this function as you can see but it gives me this error : AttributeError: 'ReviewinApp' object has no attribute 'ids'.

Comment: Please post a [minimal and reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) for people to try out.

Comment: The error ocurred at line: "user = self.ids.user_app.text". One line before, print the object self and look if it has an object ids. I couldn't test here because I ran the code and bugged before the error you are looking for.